# ThermalTake TT Esports Neptune Pro keyboard stops working - three blinking LEDs

Tags: keyboard

I have a TTEsports Neptune Pro mechanical keyboard. It has abruptly stopped working. The three num lock/capslock/scroll lock LEDs are blinking.

I have tried plugging it into another machine and the some problem exists.

Is there a resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three blinking lights appears to be some kind of 'lock keyboard' mode.

Press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>num lock</kbd>  to unlock it.